# Unable to verify a CMS signed message with webcrypto API

Tags: javascript, rsa, public-key-encryption, signature, webcrypto-api

I want to verify a CMS signed message with the JavaScript webcrypto API. The message is part of a timestamp response according to RFC 3161.

[image: Wireshark display]

So I take the signature, the content (from encapContentInfo) and the public key and pass it to the following function that imports the key and verifies the signature:

```
function verify(signature, data, publicKey, callback) {

  console.log("pubkey: " + publicKey);
  console.log("data: " + data);
  console.log("signature: " + signature);

  crypto.subtle.importKey(
    "spki",
    new Uint8Array(hexToArray(publicKey)),
    {
      name: "RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5",
      hash: {name: "SHA-1"}
    },
    false,
    ["verify"]
    )
    .then(function(publicKey){

      console.log(publicKey);

      crypto.subtle.verify(
        {
          name: "RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5",
          hash: {name: "SHA-1"}
        },
        publicKey,
        new Uint8Array(hexToArray(signature)),
        new Uint8Array(hexToArray(data))
        )
        .then(function(isvalid){
          console.log("valid: " + isvalid);
        })
        .catch(function(err){
          throw(err);
        });

    })
    .catch(function(err){
      throw(err);
    });
}
```

The output is the following:

```
pubkey: 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
data: 306b020101060c2b0601040181ad21822c16013031300d0609608648016503040201050004201b14e43e38297d534d827e351c15347f9eebc973258c8b555c044de46c5a0f02021424e3f636950c119fb3ebdb289d60d7bc637f3bd9180f32303136303431393139333931395a
signature: 7a65069868d97fb0ffcd53bca6b80daa671e1b0ac1a1d262ba2fba1525d0ca8e4998d4f49cba990f9a89c52003457ca1bbb037dee8e5e64c617af0c1ea72215b648477b052165810f4f6eb7f869ac19373b2aad1a2b5a809b8b758bdad540a5cd1f33d3c80870c7ae9c6db61dd7c7f8c346ee3c7aadc16f90ed87833a4ba771cbdc930a6dfb3fd16f5ab57de212deddc4d49c11ef825a8d996ba40e0e07c7c5788000d61169fe7512c97d29f7ff4b8ce2842e5b339dae5cef1eb517457b3e8b98bc887dda952b6346bd8345e5eb2cdd976fe5688d375551bc2a20cd7aafd1bbf6a9d102ad2a8dea620ad3ed6763f0841ec020dc1ad485ed1448ae5f5d511ef8f
CryptoKey {}
valid: false
```

As you can see, the verification fails, but I am pretty sure the signature is valid as this timestamp server is used by many people.

Is there anything wrong with my implementation?

I try to do this inside of an Firefox extension.

Edit: It seem that it is required to use the DER value of the signedAttrs field, hash it and then verify it with the certificate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it myself: You first have to decrypt the signature with the public key to get a ASN.1 object that contains the message digest.

e.g. `openssl rsautl -inkey cert.pem -pubin -in signature -out out`

[image: message digest object]

Then you take the signedAttrs object and replace the explicit tag at the beginning (0xA0) with the set tag (0x31) because of the following sentence in the RFC:

```
The IMPLICIT [0] tag in the signedAttrs is not used for the DER encoding, rather an EXPLICIT SET OF tag is used
```

Then you calculate a digest (with the same algorithm as in digestAlgorithm in signerInfo) of the set object.

The two digest values are the same if the signature is valid.